# Query with multiple joins, group_concat and million rows executes slowly

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, query-optimization

Query -

```
    SELECT s.id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.song_title SEPARATOR ', ') AS titles, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.artist_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS artists, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(al.album_title SEPARATOR ', ') AS albums, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.release_date SEPARATOR ', ') AS release_dates, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(sam.role SEPARATOR ', ') AS roles
    FROM songs s 
    INNER JOIN song_artist_mappings sam ON sam.song_id = s.id 
    INNER JOIN artists a ON sam.artist_id = a.id 
    INNER JOIN album_track_mappings atm ON atm.song_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN albums al on al.id = atm.album_id 
    GROUP BY s.id
```

Indexes available on -

```
    songs - id
    song_artist_mappings - song_id, artist_id
    album_track_mappings - song_id, album_id
    albums - id
    artists - id
```

The query returns ~2 million rows (which is the size of songs table) and takes many minutes to execute. Is there any way to optimize?

EDIT - A song (unique song id) can belong to multiple albums as well as artists. I have to display all of those as comma separated string. A small amount of data is corrupted where a song id in different rows has different title. Choosing any of those titles would be fine so I guess GROUP_CONCAT on song_title is not necessary. But then I will have to SELECT a non aggregate variable which is not listed in GROUP BY. Due to the corrupted data, I cannot group on song_title.

The query takes many minutes on InnoDB on 30GB RAM machine, even if I append LIMIT 5 to the query. No query is cached since query_cache_size is 0

EDIT 2 - The query runs much much faster when I get the same data via CakePHP associations. CakePHP splits the query into multiple queries and executes them sequentially.

[EXPLAIN SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdRMX.png)

Comment: Apart from the fact that there is no way around the fact that loading and concatenating such an amount of data IS going to take some time, I do have some 'frowns' towards the query. From the query I take it that 1 song id will (potentially) have many titles. I'd expect that `s.id` is the PK of the table, hence 1 id means 1 title. There is no need for an aggregation on `titles` IMHO, right? As for the others I imagine that through the mapping tables you end up with many to many relations, so there indeed you're going to need to concatenate those.

Comment: That said, I still expect the outcome is going to be fairly strange, most likely the order of the values will not match between fields anyway and even then. If I understand things correctly you'll end up with records along the line of  `1`, `Yesterday`,`'The beatles,Sinatra,Elvis,BoyzIIMen`, `Help!, Best of, Yesterday (single),  My Way, ...`, `1969, 1965,  1994, ...`, `writer, singer, singer, ...`   Not sure HOW you'd want to use that to be honest.

Comment: A song (unique song id) can belong to multiple albums as well as artists. I have to display all of those as comma separated string. A small amount of data is corrupted where a song id in different rows has different title. Choosing any of those titles would be fine so I guess GROUP_CONCAT on song_title is not necessary. But then I will have to SELECT a non aggregate variable which is not listed in GROUP BY. Due to the corrupted data, I cannot group on song_title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  It needs to scan 2M rows, look up several million rows in the other tables, create a multi-million row tmp table, do the `GROUP BY` (possibly without a `filesort`) and finally shovel 2M resulting rows to the client.

Well, maybe...  Which Engine are you using?  If you are using InnoDB, what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  That setting should be about 70% of *available* RAM.  That won't help when running the query on a cold cache, since there will be a lot of I/O to do.  But if you run the query a second time, it might run 10 times as fast.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can verify that the indexes are being used as expected.

Lower you expectations -- 2 million rows deserves to take some time.  What the heck are you going to do with that much output?  And do you need it more than once?

**Addenda**

A partial speedup is to have better indexes for the many:many tables (`sam` and `atm`).  In particular, a composite query would be faster.  [more details](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: Edited to add more details. I do not need the exact same query multiple times. I am trying to implement pagination manually by using LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: see Addenda.  As for LIMIT and OFFSET -- ouch.  That will be miserably slow; even slower than what you have now.  See [my blog on why not to use OFFSET for patination](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) (and what to do instead).